# Multiple skew brackets in tensor summation, e.g. $U_{[ab]}V^{[ab]}$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

I'm wondering what does $U_{[ab]}V^{[ab]}$ or $U_{[ab]}V^{(ab)}$ usually mean? I thought the double brackets meant to apply the $\text{sgn}(\pi)$ twice so $$U_{[ab]}V^{[ab]}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a,b}\left(U_{ab}\text{sgn}(\pi(ab))\cdot V^{ab}\text{sgn}(\pi(ab))\right)$$

---

For contexts, I've been asked to prove $\phi_{i} \psi_{j} v_{1}^{[i} v_{2}^{j]}=\phi_{[i} \psi_{j]} v_{1}^{[i} v_{2}^{j]}$ in differential forms.

I tried $\phi_{i} \psi_{j} v_{1}^{[i} v_{2}^{j]}=\frac{1}{2}(\phi_1\psi_2v_1^1v_2^2-\phi_2\psi_1v_1^2v_2^1)$

$\phi_{[i} \psi_{j]} v_{1}^{[i} v_{2}^{j]}=\frac{1}{2}(\phi_1\psi_2v_1^1v_2^2+\phi_2\psi_1v_1^2v_2^1)$

And they equal because the second term $=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simpler definition
$$U_{[ab]}=\tfrac 12(U_{ab}-U_{ba}).$$
To proof that
$$U_{ab}V^{[ab]}=U_{[ab]}V^{[ab]}$$
for any tensor $U$ you can first split $U$ into its symmetric and antisymmetric part
$$U_{ab}=U_{(ab)}+U_{[ab]}$$
and then show that $$U_{(ab)}V^{[ab]}=0.$$
Similarly there's an identity for a symmetric contraction: $$U_{ab}V^{(ab)}=U_{(ab)}V^{(ab)}$$

---

Hint: to show $U_{(ab)}V^{[ab]}=0$ you can use $A=-A\implies A=0$

Comment: Ah that makes sense. This is the first time I saw such thing, so am I right that those 'double brackets' never used in real life? (Other than making problem questions after class ofc)

Comment: @Steve I remember using this identity a couple times during my general relativity introduction so I guess that counts as real life use

Comment: @Steve - By double bracket notation do you mean the antisymmetrization notation? This is used ALL THE TIME in physics and it is important to get familiar with it.

Comment: @PraharMitra oh I was talking about the double use of brackets inside a single contraction. I’ve been through part ii-iii yet this is the first time I saw it. (Judging from your profile I think we’re from the same school)